# verify alert message in chrome selenium webdriver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to screenshot the image of website which exists in real. It is for make a sitemap.
Some of the website shows alert message and others doesn't 
I'm using python and selenium webdriver 
To ignore the message and to capture the image I need to verify whether site has shown alert or not. How can I do that?
Actually I tried to make a new tab instead but it's not working with my webdriver(chrome) 
I tried with using Eexpected_conditions -
if EC.alert_is_present(): to detect the alert but it is not working.

```
>from selenium import webdriver
>from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
>wd= webdriver.Chrome('C:/chromedriver.exe')
>for num in range(0, 1000):
    for num2 in range(0,26):
        print(num, num2)
        wd.get('base_url' + format(num, "03d") + alpha[num2] + '.php')
        wd.save_screenshot(savefile + format(num, "03d") + alpha[num2] + '.png')
    if EC.alert_is_present:
        wd.switch_to_alert()
        wd.switch_to_alert().accept()
```

raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)
selenium.common.exceptions.UnexpectedAlertPresentException: Alert Text: None
Message: unexpected alert open

Comment: Have you tried catching the `UnexpectedAlertPresentException` and call `wd.switch_to_alert().accept()` when it's raised?

Answer (score 1):

```
driver.switchTo().alert().getText()
```

will get you the text message of alert which you can assert.